# How long does FCM high priority message grant network access?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send messages using FCM and i am using high priority notifications in order to overcome the App standby case should it ever occur.

I was wondering if anyone has tested the duration of network access after receiving the high priority notification.

I read in a medium post that it grants around 15 minutes and this was a session by a google dev advocate. can anyone confirm this?

[How long will the device stay awake when it receives a FCM high priority message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272509/how-long-will-the-device-stay-awake-when-it-receives-a-fcm-high-priority-message) - this is my own question but has a different issue which had to be solved.

Can someone point me as to how I can test this?

EDIT:

The medium link is :
https://medium.com/google-developers/testing-app-standby-b8b90c4f411

Comment: Hi Kushan. Linking the *medium post* would be nice.

Comment: added the link... sorry for the late response... timezones are a pain :)

Comment: Thanks Kushan. I get the use-case you're getting at and I think using the [Firebase Job Dispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) is what you could use, instead of knowing how long the network access is granted (which can be different per device). Check out this [Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/using-firebase-cloud-messaging-with.html) which discusses a scenario similar to yours.

Comment: Did you manage to find the answer ? I'm using high priority FCM but often have timeouts when trying to contact my server after the message (and after a long idle time). It seems the device block the internet access to my app even if it's non optimized.

Comment: This might be helpful https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages